# Help understanding a definitive integral

Tags: math, matlab

I am trying to translate a function in a book into code, using MATLAB and C#.

I am first trying to get the function to work properly in MATLAB.

Here are the instructions:

[image]

The variables are:

```
xt and m can be ignored.
zMax = Maximum Sensor Range (100)
zkt = Sensor Measurement (49)
zkt* = What sensor measurement should have been (50)
oHit = Std Deviation of my measurement (5)
```

I have written the first formula, N(zkt;zkt*,oHit) in MATLAB as this:

```
hitProbabilty = (1/sqrt( 2*pi * (oHit^2) ))...
                * exp(-0.5 * (((zkt- zktStar) ^ 2) / (oHit^2))  );
```

This gives me the Gaussian curve I expect.

I have an issue with the definite integral below, I do not understand how to turn this into a real number, because I get horrible values out my code, which is this:

```
func = @(x) hitProbabilty * zkt * x;
normaliser = quad(func, 0, max) ^ -1;  
hitProbabilty = normaliser * hitProbabilty;
```

Can someone help me with this integral? It is supposed to normalize my curve, but it just goes crazy.... (I am doing this for zkt 0:1:100, with everything else the same, and graphing the probability it should output.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) [ERF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/erf.html) (available in basic MATLAB)

---

**EDIT1:**

As [@Jim Brissom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644037/help-understanding-a-definitive-integral/3644123#3644123) mentioned, the cumulative distribution function (CDF) is related to the error function by:

```
normcdf(X) = (1 + erf(X/sqrt(2)) / 2 ,   where X~N(0,1)
```

Note that [NORMCDF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/normcdf.html) requires the Statistics Toolbox

---

**EDIT2:**

I think there's been a small confusion seeing the comments.. The above only compute the normalizing factor, so if you want to compute the final probability over a certain range of values, you should do this:

```
zMax = 100;                         %# Maximum Sensor Range
zktStar = 50;                       %# What sensor measurement should have been
oHit = 5;                           %# Std Deviation of my measurement

%# p(0<z<zMax) = p(z<zMax) - p(z<0)
ncdf = diff( normcdf([0 zMax], zktStar, oHit) );
normaliser = 1 ./ ncdf;

zkt = linspace(0,zMax,500);         %# Sensor Measurement, 500 values in [0,zMax]
hitProbabilty = normpdf(zkt, zktStar, oHit) * normaliser;

plot(zkt, hitProbabilty)
xlabel('z^k_t'), ylabel('P_{hit}(z^k_t)'), title('Measurement Probability')
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but which part of my code do I replace with the error function?
Do you mean instead of computing normaliser?

Comment: Should I wait until after I compute all hitProbabilities, then do the ERF on that array? Then do I multiple the original array by the output of ERF?

Comment: n = 1 ./ (normcdf((zMax-zktStar)/oHit) - 0.5);
Always gives me the value 2, for all values, 0-100? erf() always gives me back 2?

Comment: not really, try: `plot( 1 ./ (normcdf(([0:zMax]-zktStar)/oHit) - 0.5) )` and you will see a curve (`Inf` in the middle because we're dividing by zero!)

Comment: It gives me a very odd graph, like an upside L, but mirrored horizontally and vertically as well.

Comment: isnt zMax a constant in your equations? besides it doesnt make any sense if zMax is less than the mean zktStar, therefor you should only plot from 50 to 100, ie `[zktStar:zMax]`

Comment: Brilliant, this looks much more like what I'm after, I'm not sure about the actual values... I will have to see when I move on to the next equations if they match up. But thank you very much for your help. This was very puzzling for me!

Comment: @James: I made a correction to the normalizer formula, please see the edits.. I would still double check everything above, just to be on the safe side :)

Answer (score 2):

The N in your code is just the well-known gaussian or normal distribution. I am mentioning this because since you re-implemented it in Matlab, it seems you missed that, seeing as how it is obviously already implemented in Matlab.

Integrating the normal distribution will yield a cumulative distribution function, available in Matlab for the normal distribution via `normcdf`. The ncdf can be written in terms of `erf`, which is probably what Amro was talking about.

Using normcdf avoids integrating manually.

Comment: I see, so over my loop of 100 values, I should use on the array, this gives me another array.. The articles multiplies the normal with the value, should I do this, or does the function do this for me?

-- Do you also mean I can re-write my Gaussian function too? How would I go about doing this? I'm not really maths orientated, only being forced into it out of necessity, forgive my ignorance.

Comment: You do not need to implement the normal distribution, in Matlab at least. You will have to do this in C#, though (unless you use a library, but this is a different matter). As for normalization: a cumulative distribution function f(x) expresses the probability that a random variable lies in the interval (-inf, x], which is basically the same as saying that the random variable is smaller or equal to x. normalcdf already includes the integration part, but not the power-to-minus-one part. This part probably refers to the percent point function, which is just the inverse of a cdf.

Comment: I think I understand, so I can replace my code with:
measurements = 0:1:100;
actualDistance = 50;
oHit = 50;

hitProbabilities = normpdf(measurements, actualDistance, oHit );
normalisedProbabilities = edf(hitProbabilities);
plot(measurements, normalisedProbabilities, measurements, normalisedProbabilities);

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the Gaussian function in instructions is a standard Gaussian function, so I don't have to re-write it in MATLAB and C#!

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need the result for the integral.

From Mathematica. The Calc is

```
hitProbabilty[zkt_] := (1/Sqrt[2*Pi*oHit^2])*Exp[-0.5*(((zkt - zktStar)^2)/(oHit^2))];
Integrate[hitProbabilty[zkt], {zkt, 0, zMax}];
```

The result is (just for copy/paste)

```
((1.2533141373155001*oHit*zktStar*Erf[(0.7071067811865476*Sqrt[zktStar^2])/oHit])/
Sqrt[zktStar^2] + 
(1.2533141373155001*oHit*(zMax-zktStar)*Erf[(0.7071067811865476*Sqrt[(zMax-zktStar)^2])/oHit])/
   Sqrt[(zMax-zktStar)^2])/(2*oHit*Sqrt[2*Pi])
```

Where Erf[] is the error function

HTH!