# How to implement this function in MATLAB?

Tags: math, matlab

I am using a book with a function I would like to use. However I don't think I am getting the correct values from my function.

Here is the instruction from the book:

[image]

Here is the function as I have created it in MATLAB:

```
function [ shortProbability ] = pShort( zkt, zktStar, short)

if zkt > zktStar
    shortProbability = 0;
else
    normalizer = 1/(1-exp(-short*zktStar));
    shortProbability = normalizer * (short * exp(-short*zkt));
end

end
```

The values I am plugging in are:

```
zkt = 0:1:100
zktStar = 50;
short = 0.01;
```

However my graph doesn't behave like the one which I am supposed to end up with, which is this:

[image]

I am getting this from the graph, which looks correct, however I don't think it is being normalized properly:

[image]

Can anyone help me to correct this function?

Comment: When p(zkt) is a probability density function, to integral vom -inf to +inf should equal 1. By just looking at your plot, the distribution does doesn't look wrong.

Comment: @James: Assuming we're supposed to be looking at the blue graph, that looks about right (at least as far as normalisation).  It's roughly a rectangular function of height 0.02 and width 50, so has area equal to about 1.  Therefore it's a valid PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). You can use [EXPPDF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/exppdf.html) and [EXPCDF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/expcdf.html) from the Statistics Toolbox:

```
normalizer = 1 ./ ( expcdf(zktStar,1/short) - expcdf(0,1/short) );
shortProbability = exppdf(zkt, 1/short) * normalizer;
```

and it should be equivalent to what you have...

---

This is what I get when I combine it with the graph from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644037/help-understanding-a-definitive-integral/3644076#3644076):

[image]

To confirm, we compute the area under each of the curves (close enough to `1`):

```
>> trapz(zkt,hitProbabilty)
ans =
     1

>> trapz(zkt,shortProbability)
ans =
       1.0077
```

Comment: Thanks again Amro, your really helping me out! I've been able to convert these MATLAB functions to C# by using the MathsDotNet library, they contain a lot of useful methods for these statistic functions.